# Find 'x' for a probability after getting p(x) from logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

With this dataset and logistic regression model:

```
dat <- data.frame(time=rep(seq(1,10), times=3), response=c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1, 0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1))

mod <- glm(response ~ time, data=dat, family="binomial")
```

how to calculate `time` when given a probability, say `0.5`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such "find x given y" problem is a root-finding problem.

You question is somehow special. The GLM `response ~ time` implies that the logistic curve in this case is a monotonic function of `time`. So for any target probability, there is only one root. This makes it trivial to apply any numerical method to find this root. Let's just use `uniroot`, which is very verbose.

```
## we want to find the root of this function
## i.e., where it crosses 0
f <- function (tm, model, prob.target) {
  predict(model, newdata = data.frame(time = tm), type = "response") - prob.target
}

## try different lower bound 'lwr' and upper bound 'upr'
## until you see that the curve crosses the horizontal line at 0
lwr <- 0
upr <- 10
curve(f(x, mod, 0.5), lwr, upr)
abline(h = 0, lty = 2)
```

[image: good]

```
## use this 'lwr' and 'upr' for uniroot()
uniroot(f, c(lwr, upr), model = mod, prob.target = 0.5)$root
#[1] 5.160737
```

---

> I see. I asked the question because @FP0 calculated the time as 4.68/0.94 = 5.16 in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/583223), so I thought maybe there is a simple relationship that I'm missing.

Because the analytical expression of this GLM is known:

**log(p / (1 - p)) = intercept + slope * time**

When p = 0.5, the left hand side is 0. So the root is simply:

```
time = -(intercept / slope)
```

The **R** code is:

```
unname(-(mod$coef[1] / mod$coef[2]))
#[1] 5.160737
```

So, I showed how to do this both analytically and numerically. I prioritized numerical one because Stack Overflow is a coding website :D